# Simple crypto library in Python

Tags: python, security, cryptography

Is this code (also available at [github](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt/blob/master/src/simplecrypt/__init__.py) with [tests](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt/blob/master/src/simplecrypt/tests.py), [example](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt/blob/master/src/simplecrypt/example.py), and [description of algorithms](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt#algorithms)) correct and secure? It follows the recommendations [here](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html) as far as I can tell.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256, HMAC
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Random.random import getrandbits
from Crypto.Util import Counter


EXPANSION_COUNT = 10000
AES_KEY_LEN = 256
SALT_LEN = 128
HASH = SHA256
HEADER = b'sc\x00\x00'

# lengths here are in bits, but pcrypto uses block size in bytes
HALF_BLOCK = AES.block_size*8//2
assert HALF_BLOCK <= SALT_LEN  # we use a subset of the salt as nonce



def encrypt(password, data):
    '''
    Encrypt some data.  Input can be bytes or a string (which will be encoded
    using UTF-8).

    @param password: The secret value used as the basis for a key.
     This should be as long as varied as possible.  Try to avoid common words.

    @param data: The data to be encrypted.

    @return: The encrypted data, as bytes.
    '''
    data = _str_to_bytes(data)
    _assert_encrypt_length(data)
    salt = _random_bytes(SALT_LEN//8)
    hmac_key, cipher_key = _expand_keys(password, salt)
    counter = Counter.new(HALF_BLOCK, prefix=salt[:HALF_BLOCK//8])
    cipher = AES.new(cipher_key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(data)
    hmac = _hmac(hmac_key, HEADER + salt + encrypted)
    return HEADER + salt + encrypted + hmac


def decrypt(password, data):
    '''
    Decrypt some data.  Input must be bytes.

    @param password: The secret value used as the basis for a key.
     This should be as long as varied as possible.  Try to avoid common words.

    @param data: The data to be decrypted, typically as bytes.

    @return: The decrypted data, as bytes.  If the original message was a
    string you can re-create that using `result.decode('utf8')`.
    '''
    _assert_not_string(data)
    _assert_header_sc(data)
    _assert_header_version(data)
    _assert_decrypt_length(data)
    raw = data[len(HEADER):]
    salt = raw[:SALT_LEN//8]
    hmac_key, cipher_key = _expand_keys(password, salt)
    hmac = raw[-HASH.digest_size:]
    hmac2 = _hmac(hmac_key, data[:-HASH.digest_size])
    _assert_hmac(hmac_key, hmac, hmac2)
    counter = Counter.new(HALF_BLOCK, prefix=salt[:HALF_BLOCK//8])
    cipher = AES.new(cipher_key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)
    return cipher.decrypt(raw[SALT_LEN//8:-HASH.digest_size])



class DecryptionException(Exception): pass
class EncryptionException(Exception): pass

def _assert_not_string(data):
    # warn confused users
    if isinstance(data, str):
        raise DecryptionException('Data to decrypt must be bytes; ' +
        'you cannot use a string because no string encoding will accept all possible characters.')

def _assert_encrypt_length(data):
    # for AES this is never going to fail
    if len(data) > 2**HALF_BLOCK:
        raise EncryptionException('Message too long.')

def _assert_decrypt_length(data):
    if len(data) &lt; len(HEADER) + SALT_LEN//8 + HASH.digest_size:
        raise DecryptionException('Missing data.')

def _assert_header_sc(data):
    if len(data) &lt; 2 or data[:2] != HEADER[:2]:
        raise DecryptionException('Data passed to decrypt were not generated by simple-crypt (bad header).')

def _assert_header_version(data):
    if len(data) &lt; len(HEADER) or data[:len(HEADER)] != HEADER:
        raise DecryptionException('The data appear to be encrypted with a more recent version of simple-crypt (bad header). ' +
        'Please update the library and try again.')

def _assert_hmac(key ,hmac, hmac2):
    # https://www.isecpartners.com/news-events/news/2011/february/double-hmac-verification.aspx
    if _hmac(key, hmac) != _hmac(key, hmac2):
        raise DecryptionException('Bad password or corrupt / modified data.')

def _expand_keys(password, salt):
    if not salt: raise ValueError('Missing salt.')
    if not password: raise ValueError('Missing password.')
    key_len = AES_KEY_LEN // 8
    # the form of the prf below is taken from the code for PBKDF2
    keys = PBKDF2(_str_to_bytes(password), salt, dkLen=2*key_len,
        count=EXPANSION_COUNT, prf=lambda p,s: HMAC.new(p,s,HASH).digest())
    return keys[:key_len], keys[key_len:]

def _random_bytes(n):
    return bytes(getrandbits(8) for _ in range(n))

def _hmac(key, data):
    return HMAC.new(key, data, HASH).digest()

def _str_to_bytes(data):
    try: return data.encode('utf8')
    except AttributeError: return data
```

Finally, see also [this HN thread](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4962983) which identified many issues in an earlier version of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a crypto expert, but I see that at least your decryption code is vulnerable to verification timing attacks (see e.g. here: http://rdist.root.org/2009/05/28/timing-attack-in-google-keyczar-library/)

Comment: you're right, thanks, although it has been fixed since i posted here (i now compare the hash of the hmacs).  i will update the code in the question (for the record i had `if hmac != hmac2`)

Comment: @andrewcooke, comparing hashes of hmacs is still a verification timing vulnarability, only of a different kind. You have to switch to a constant-time comparison method which executes in exactly the same time regardless of the string possible inequality location, the referenced page contains one such algorithm.

Comment: it's the solution described here https://www.isecpartners.com/news-events/news/2011/february/double-hmac-verification.aspx - can you explain why that's wrong?  is it a different problem?  they argue (afaict) that it's equivalent to a constant time comparison (that link is in the code next to the comparison)

Comment: @andrewcooke, double hashing makes this vulnerability much harder to exploit, but if you approach this from the cryptographer's point of view (in terms of a game played by an adversary against your crypto implementation), then this "new" approach still does disclose *some* information about the ciphertext, while a proper algorithm must disclose no information. It is not easily exploitable under current knowledge, but as usual this is just a matter of time and theory. I don't understand why not simply use a constant time implementation which is proven to be resistant to this attack.

Comment: i want code that follows clear guidelines from standard authorities.  as far as i can see that reference is clear and authoritative.  you started by saying you were not an expert.  now you are arguing against an article by someone who, as far as i can tell, is.  in my (unexpert) opinion, either is fine. edit:  hmm, although it looks like i may have screwed up my implementation.  i will fix that later.

Comment: fixed.  and thanks again (particularly since there was an error there).  this isn't personal.  i understand your argument, but my main goal in writing this code is that it is documented behaviour from standard sources (and that i think it makes sense).